# Gulp. Перемещение файлов в соседнюю директорию

Tags: javascript, gulp, babel, gulp-babel

Упрощенная структура проекта [выглядит так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqGri.png). Файлы JavaScript, которые находятся в каталоге **es6**, должны быть перемещены в соседний каталог **js**.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('build-js', function () {
    gulp.src('app/core/**/es6/**/*.js')
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ["env"]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(???)); // нужно переместить в ../js
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать это в Gulp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему с помощью пакета gulp-rename и простого регулярного выражения:

```
...
.pipe(rename(function (file) {
    file.dirname = file.dirname.replace(/es6/g, 'js'); 
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/core'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать пакет [merge-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream).

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('build-js', function () {
    // Задаем пути
    var paths = ['app/core/AdminTools/','app/core/Permissions/']
    var streams = paths.map(function (path) {
        // выполнение действий для каждого раздела
        return gulp.src(path + 'es6/**/.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ["env"]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path + "js"));
    });
// объединяем потоки
return merge(streams);
});
```

Comment: Исходные пути задавать сложно, потому что их несколько сотен)

Comment: @mrOrlando не плохой вариант))